# Change CkEditor's background color with jQuery methods

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I need to change background color of CkEditor, on some basic jQuery methods, like ready, change, etc.

Tried with things like:

```
$(document).on('click','.change-task-status', function(e){
   $(".cke_editable").css("background-color", 'red');
})
```

... but nothing happens.

Can you help me how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

PS. yes, I do have jQuery adapter loaded on page.

UPDATE:

Some improvement is made - when I run next code in console, it changes background color

```
$( ".cke_wysiwyg_frame" ).contents().find( ".cke_editable" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
```

Now just to find why it does not execute in code...

Comment: Is your click function working fine ? just put a alert there and see

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one and see.
    $(document).on('click','.change-task-status', function(){
       $(".cke_editable").css("background", 'red');
    })
```

Comment: Can you submit a fiddle ?

Comment: $(".cke_editable").css("background", 'red');
Try that in your console

Comment: $(".cke_editable").css("background", 'red'); Try that in your console

Comment: Good point, nothing changes in this case, it's still white background

Comment: Can you at least put the html code here.So that I can give you working answer :)

Comment: Ok, I made a bit of improvement. Can you please updated part of my primary post